# How to split a MySQL table file?

Tags: mysql, partitioning, tablespaces

I have a table in a MySQL database for which `innodb_file_per_table` is enabled. One of my tables is about 20GB and growing. How can I partition the table into separate files?

Suppose that I have a table named `tab1` that is stored on `/var/lib/mysql/db_name/tab1.frm` and the size is about 20GB. I want to partition that table to split into 2 files `tab1-1.frm` and `tab1-2.frm` each one sized at 10GB.

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE cdr (
     gid bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     id bigint(20) NOT NULL,
     start datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
     clid varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
     src varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
     channel varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
     duration int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     uniqueid varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
     dnid varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
     service varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
     cost int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
     PRIMARY KEY (gid),
     UNIQUE KEY id (id,prefix),
     KEY start (start),
     KEY clid (clid),
     KEY service (service)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=37024605 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: MySQL has some good documentation on Partitioning: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning.html . Without further info on things like MySQL Version, table structure, etc, however we can't be much more help.

Comment: @IGGt, Thanks. I couldn't find the proper answer for my question. Let me update my question.

Comment: Can you show the table schema with `show create table ...`? If you are inserting new rows, could you add also a example of insert?

Comment: What benefit do you hope to gain by limiting pieces to 10GB?  I ask because` PARTITION` does _not_ automatically give any benefits.

Comment: I don't see `prefix` in the table definition??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume it is the `.ibd` file that is 20GB, not the `.frm`?

If you want two physically separate tables you could copy tab1-1 into tab1-2 (so you have two copies) then Delete half the data from each. You'd still need to `Optimize` both tables afterwards to shrink them.

Using the MySQL partition option you would have one table `tab1`, which you would partition by some range (e.g. all ID's below 10000 in partition 1, 10001 - 20000 in partition 2 etc.). This would then show up on your filesystem as two (or more) separate files (in the form of `tab1.frm` and various files like `tab1#p#partition1.ibd`, `tab1#p#partition2.ibd`).
It wouldn't give you control over the filesizes however.

In the above example, if all your ID's were below 10000 for instance, it would make no difference to your filesizes.

If you provide the table structure, and mysql version it would help.

**UPDATE: 2015-04-13 11:44 (GMT+1):**

Looking at your table structure, the first thing I see is that you are going to have problems because you have a `Primary key` and a `Unique Key`.

> All columns used in the partitioning expression for a partitioned
>   table must be part of every unique key that the table may have.
>
> In other words, every unique key on the table must use every column in
>   the table's partitioning expression. (This also includes the table's
>   primary key, since it is by definition a unique key.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html

At present, any attempt at partitioning will result in an error:

e.g.

`Error Code: 1503. A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function`

or

`Error Code: 1503. A UNIQUE INDEX must include all columns in the table's partitioning function`

I would recomend looking at some of the following first:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-limitations.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html
- http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint (credit to Rick James for this one)

Also, test this on a non-live server, as it may well take quite some time to build the partitions, which you wouldn't want to do on a Live database.

**UPDATE: 2015-04-27 09:52 (GMT+1):**

It seems you have some decisions to make. . .

In order to use the `Start` column, you would need to add `start` to both the Primary Key (PK) and the Unique Key.

```
    ALTER TABLE `test`.`cdr` 
    DROP PRIMARY KEY
    ,DROP INDEX `id`
    ,ADD PRIMARY KEY (`gid`,`start`)
    ,ADD UNIQUE INDEX `id` (`id` ASC, `prefix` ASC, `start` ASC);
```

The affect on your PK would be negligible (as long as you DON'T write directly to it - which would defeat the point of the auto-increment anyway).

It would however, potentially cause a problem for your Unique Key, as it would now only be unique across `id,prefix,start`.

e.g.
`insert into test.cdr (id,prefix,start) values (100,'abc','2015-04-27 09:19:00'),(100,'abc','2015-04-27 09:19:01');`

will become valid, whereas previously it would have generated a duplicate key error.

so you would need to consider how important that uniqueness is.

If it IS very important, you may want to consider partitioning by `id` instead, but that depends on what your data looks like as to how easy that would be (and using `id,prefix` as your PK, and converting `gid` to a standard (not unique) `key`.

If it isn't very important, then you could convert the Unique Key to a standard key, and make `gid,start` your PK.

Comment: OK. Let me check it.

Comment: I test it. I exactly got that 2 errors you mentioned. I try to solve it and read about it too much. I have to change the table structure but i don't know how to change it? I add that i emphasis on using `start` column as partition expression key because of the  better ‍`Partition Pruning`.

Comment: see above update:

Comment: Thank you so much. I can't make `id,prefix,start` as unique key, because on `start` column. We may have records to insert in a same time so if the `start` column be unique, we cant have valid data insertion. By the other hand, if we make `gid, start` as Primary index, again both of the are unique, aren't they?

Comment: You can still insert records with the same `start` time, as long you don't insert records with the same `id` **AND** `prefix` **AND** `starttime`, as the Unique index would encompass all three columns.
 
As for the PK, as long as you don't insert anything yourself into the `gid` column, the `auto-increment` will take care of the uniqueness.

Comment: And what about create Primary key from `(gid , start)`? Isn't it better to create Primary Key just from `gid`?

Comment: That's one of those questions that has many different answers depending on who you speak to. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737190/composite-primary-key-or-not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159087/composite-primary-keys-versus-unique-object-id-field

My preference is for a PK made from just `gid`. But then you can't partition using `start`. Ultimately it comes down to what is going to work best for your situation, in your database with your applications.

Comment: In my case, Creating `gid` as Primary Key is enough, and as i read your links, creating `start` column as primary key is surplus. So How to partition without creating `start` as Primary key? Is there any problem?

Comment: Really I think at this point you perhaps need to go back to the start and look at whether you really need to split / partition your data.

Comment: If you want to continue with partitioning then you can no longer partition based on `start`. That leaves you with two indexes the PK `id` and the Unique Key `gid,prefix`. One of these will have to go. Could you make the unique key `gid,prefix` the PK, and then make the PK `id` a standard key (it can still be auto_increment)? Again, you would need to test the affect of this on you application / system. You could then partition based on `gid` (but that's not optimal - I would redo the index to be `prefix,gid` but that may be a problem if you have queries using that index)

Comment: Is it possible to do `ALTER TABLE test.cdr
    DROP PRIMARY KEY
    ,DROP INDEX id
    ,ADD PRIMARY KEY (gid)
    ,ADD UNIQUE INDEX id (id ASC, prefix ASC, start ASC);` for partition base on `start` column?

Comment: No, because a) your PK hasn't changed, and b) `start` doesn't appear in your PK.

Comment: Hey man, thank you so much for your answer. At last i deploy your query and now i could partition my table.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the date to the PK and replace the unique key with a key. Then you have to handle the unique check in the application.

Another solution is to add for example a Year column derived from start, then you add Year to PK and unique key. Then it should work to partition by year.